# How to force coefficients to be non-negative in Linear regression/Lasso?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using Spark's Linear regression (pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression) in python. However, I would like to force coefficients to be all positive for every feature (not negative), is there any way I can accomplish that? I was looking in the documentation but could not find a way to accomplish that. I understand I may not get the best solution, but I need the weights to be non-negative.

BTW, Scikit Learn Lasso has a parameter called positive for this request.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
lin = Lasso(alpha=0.0001,precompute=True,max_iter=1000,
            positive=True, random_state=9999, selection='random')
lin.fit(X,y)
```

Thanks

Comment: Here is a function for NNLS https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html